# Пожалуйста подскажите как понять такой запрос (оператор NOT)

Tags: sql, mysql

Пожалуйста подскажите как понять такой запрос:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE NOT(registration_date <= NOW()-INTERVAL 1 MONTH);
```

Что тут значит оператор NOT и может есть какая то особенность использования NOT с данными типа DATE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Выбрать все записи, которые НЕ старше одного месяца.
Смысла, имхо, нет: можно смело написать

```
>
```

Но лучше посмотрите что скажет explain.

Comment: Не всё так просто: 

    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users // 2500 строк
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE registration_date <= NOW()-INTERVAL 1 MONTH // 2448
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE NOT(registration_date <= NOW()-INTERVAL 1 MONTH) // 0

куда могли деться 52 строки? вероятно есть какая то особенность при использовании с типом DATETIME, TIMESTAMP....

Comment: NULL имеется?